# wifi connection slow and weak on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, 14.04

I am pretty new to ubuntu so please bear with me,

So basically I installed ubuntu14.04 on my Samsung 900x laptop, and the wifi signal becomes very weak and I couldn't connect to the internet at all, but the wifi on my Mac is fine. I'm wondering if anyone would have any idea how to solve this?

I tried all the methods on the following links and they didn't seem to work.

http://zeroset.mnim.org/2014/04/22/unstable-wifi-connection-on-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-ctrl-event-disconnected-reason4-locally_generated1/

http://itsfoss.com/speed-up-slow-wifi-connection-ubuntu/

To update: I do get a connection at times, but it's super unstable and lasts for only a few seconds..

However, my samsung laptop appears to have a strong and stable connection to my phone's hotspot network...but my mac has a very strong and stable connection to the home wifi...any idea?

Comment: have you found a solution to this? I'm having the same problem

Comment: Please review http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos and then [edit] the info into your question.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing issues with extremely slow wireless to no wireless. The fix for me was to install a newer kernel.

My basic specs:

Linux Mint 17 cinnamon 64 bit

Kernel: 3.14.5-031405-lowlatency (low latency for audio mixing)

Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)

Mint 17 comes stock with the same kernel as Ubuntu 14.04

I downloaded the following kernels from

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.14.5-utopic/

linux-image-3.14.5-031405-lowlatency_3.14.5-031405.201405311735_amd64.deb linux-headers-3.14.5-031405_3.14.5-031405.201405311735_all.deb
 linux-headers-3.14.5-031405-lowlatency_3.14.5-031405.201405311735_amd64.deb

That location also has generic kernels as well, which should work just fine.

You should be able to install those with gdebi without any issues.
 Let me know if that works for you.